# ORACLE APEX - Local install

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a way to install apex on the machine automatically without the need of typing commands, like an exe file or something, I tried to install it manually, and did not work for me, it give me errors on the part before the image.

Comment: APEX runs in a database. What did you do, exactly? What is "the part before the image"?

Comment: Did you follow the **Installation Guide**? It exists for a reason.